# php registration with paypal account authentication without deduction

Tags: php, paypal

I am creating registration form with PayPal ( on site with card). I am using PayPal here just for account authentication of client so there should not be any deduction of money but when i send request with zero price it does not accept as you know PayPal does not accept 0 price so what can be the solution here? how can i resolve it?

Comment: @BugFinder That is not true! PayPal API contains methods for authenticating user accounts - simply to find out whether a user has a PayPal account or not. Anybody deducting and refunding money to do this should hang programming on a nail and learn rather to dig sewers...

Comment: Hmm, most places Ive dealt with have required a payment to verify paypal :( - just like paypal itself deducts money from your bank account to verify it.

Comment: @BugFinder But this is not about verifying the credit card - even this is done not by deducting and refunding money! This is only about veryfying that You have a PayPal account registered.

Comment: No I know, but I used the bank as example, I've signed up for a few things and a minimal payment was taken if it wasnt instantly deducting a payment (such as ebay, or, the like) they took a paypment and gave it back.